How to send transactions correctly and efficiently in python
I was wondering what is the best way to send a transaction and ensure it gets processed. At the moment i am using this python code that sends an already signed transaction:
from solana.rpc.commitment import Confirmed
from solana.rpc.core import UnconfirmedTxError
from solana.rpc.types import TxOpts
from solders.transaction import VersionedTransaction 


    async def send_transaction(async_client: AsyncClient, signed_txn: VersionedTransaction) -> str:
        opts = TxOpts(
            skip_preflight=False,
            preflight_commitment=Confirmed,
            skip_confirmation=False,
        )
        try:
            result = await async_client.send_raw_transaction(txn=bytes(signed_txn), opts=opts)
            transaction_id = json.loads(result.to_json())["result"]
            return transaction_id
        except UnconfirmedTxError:
            raise Exception("Transaction confirmation timed out. Please set a higher priority fee")

Sometimes this code works well and transactions are processed and confirmed, but other times I get the UnconfirmedTxError, which contains this message: "Unable to confirm transaction <transaction_id>". Sometimes this happens even if I set a very high priority fee for the transaction.
My question is: when i catch the UnconfirmedTxError, is it safe to retry sending the transaction right away, or is there the risk that the same transaction will be executed twice? Should i perform any additional checks before retrying?
Overall, am I using the correct approach for sending transactions? Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Looking through the solana-py code, it looks like it'll usually do the right thing. You're forcing send_raw_transaction to also confirm the transaction, which eventually calls into https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/blob/7f2f3cb8e4028cddc5d550e39f66e031942a9884/src/solana/rpc/async_api.py#L1126
In confirm_transaction however, if last_valid_block_height isn't provided, there's a hardcoded 90 second timeout at https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/blob/7f2f3cb8e4028cddc5d550e39f66e031942a9884/src/solana/rpc/async_api.py#L1160
This isn't always correct -- if there's a lot of forking, your transaction's blockhash might be valid for longer than 90 seconds, which means there's a small (but possible) chance that your transaction lands after the 90 second wait.
If you want the confirmation logic to be totally correct, you'll need to set the last_valid_block_height in TxOpts to whatever came out of RPC with your blockhash. If you do that, then you're sure the transaction will never succeed if confirm_transaction fails.
After that, if confirm_transaction fails, you can safely re-sign and send the transaction.

Thanks, very clear answer!
